# Jquery Closest to find div element

Tags: jquery

Upon pressing a button , I would like to find the closest div to it. 
In the following code, when I press the "myButton" button, closest returns the div with id="outerDiv" where I'm interested in finding the div with id="innerDiv".

As far as I understand both divs are parents of the button so I don't quite understand what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
   $(".buttons").click(function(e){
    alert(e.target.id)
    alert($(e.target).closest("div").attr("id"))    
    });    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outerDiv">
<table id="positions">
<div id="innerDiv">
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>id</th>
<th>button</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>omer</td>
<td>123</td>
<td><button id="myButton" class="buttons">Click</button></td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this scenario, the innerDiv will not be within the table because the markup is invalid in newer browsers. Therefore the closest div will be the parent, unfortunately. You'll need to use `.find()` on closest with this markup.

Comment: You can not have a div as a direct child of a table, it's invalid markup. And if you use the DOM inspector in the browser, you'll see that the browser moves the div to outside the table to try an fix your mistake.

Comment: The markup. You can't have a div that wraps a table row within a table. that is `invalid`. Try inspecting your markup yourslef.

Comment: for what purpose you are placing div inside table

Comment: I have a table in which for each row there is an hidden row, so for in fact I'm interested in grouping each 2 rows in one element with an id which will represent both. I thought I can use div for that

Answer (score 1):

Placing div inside table tag is not proper.If you need div with id 'innerDiv' try it

```
 $(function () {
        $(".buttons").click(function (e) {
            //alert(e.target.id)
            alert($(e.target).closest("table").find('div').attr("id"))
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your structure like this (although you can make it as per your needs) its just a demo:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
<table id="positions">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='innerDiv1'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>button</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>omer</td>
                        <td>123</td>
                        <td><button id='myButton1' class="buttons">Click</button></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='innerDiv2'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>button</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>omer</td>
                        <td>123</td>
                        <td><button id='myButton2' class="buttons">Click</button></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you can test it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/yH4YH/1/

Comment: What i'm looking is a way to surround the two rows (and not the table) with an element and then find its id. which element can i use?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(function()
            {
               $(".buttons").click(function(e){
                alert(e.target.id)
                alert($(e.target).closest("div").attr("id"))    
                });    
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="innerDiv">
        <table id="positions">
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>button</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>omer</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td><button id="myButton" class="buttons">Click</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is working, just make validation to your html code by moving

> `<table id="positions">`

and

> `</table>`

into div.